# How would a situation where rescue is impossible be handled?

Tags: failure

The President of the United States famously had a speech prepared for the eventuality of the Apollo 11 crew getting stuck on the moon and unable to be rescued.

What other plans for similar situations, where crews are alive but in a situation that cannot be recovered, exist? Both modern and historical examples are of interest.

Specifically I'm asking about how the situation would be handled, what the crew might do, what the ground staff might do, what statements might be made public etc. Anything related to the handling of it, including covering it up.

Comment: Following! But "covering up" is probably impossible.  "Crewperson Jones didn't return from space." "Why not?" <eyes shift wildly>

Comment: @OrganicMarble Hypothetically, you could imagine covering up a death due to incompetence or cost-cutting and presenting it as an unavoidable accident, or a mistake by the victim.

Comment: I think this is an intersting question, but I also agree it is very broad.  Voting to close ad to broad, maybe narrow and ask as a few different questions?

Comment: @OrganicMarble the USSR covered up quite a lot of space related deaths.

Comment: @JamesJenkins you want me to ask four separate questions? Seems like spamming but if that's what you want it looks like I'll have to do it.

Comment: @user "citation needed"

Comment: @OrganicMarble I thought this was pretty well established. For example, they covered up an accident that was very similar to the Apollo 1 fire.

Comment: @user I thought your question was about accidents *in space*. There are a lot of dumb rumors about secret Soviet deaths in space.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm not suggesting it happened, I'm asking if there is any evidence of plans to cover it up if it did happen.

Comment: I totally get that. You brought up the past Soviet coverups, not me.

Comment: @user it closed as to broad and currently has 2 re-open votes, give it a day or so and see if it gets re-opened. If it does no worries, I was wrong.  If it does not get re-opened consider narrowing it.